# How to use "times" word on object search?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example:

Task 1 needs object a.

Task 2 needs object b.

Task 3 needs object c.

If the robot could know the position of object a and c by method 1.

That means the robot use method 1 to prevent running object search module twice.

Therefore, I use times for object search module.

Which usage is correct, or totally not correct:

1. The robot saves two times of object search by using method 1.
2. The robot saves two object search times by using method 1.

Thank you~

Comment: I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly what it is you're asking. Can you give us a bit more information?

Comment: My guess is that the OP is asking about the the time it takes for the robot to search for something, so if one such "object searches" takes a certain time (let's say 1 second to give it a value) and the robot uses aforementioned  "method 1" he saves time. If that is the case, I'd go with sentence 2 (if one such object search times has a fixed value, e.g. 1 second) even though it still is awkwardly phrased. Still, I'm not sure if that is the question.

Comment: I want to ask how to use "times" word. "two times of object search" is correct or "two object search times" is correct?

Comment: A possible alternative: *The robot saves two object searches by using method 1.*

Comment: The problem is the word "times". It can mean several very different things - "instances", "period of time" and "multiply". I would avoid it here as it sounds like the latter when paired with "two".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information provided I would say that "two object search times" would be correct. It is still an awkwardly constructed sentence, better would be something along the lines of: "By using method 1, the robot saves the time it takes to run the object search module twice."

That is because time or times is not something with a specific value (unless you assign it one) when used in this context. Running the search module takes time (be it 1 second or 2 hours) but if the robot runs this module twice it still only takes **time** not two **times**. You can use the plural when you say: "the robot runs the object search module 2 times" because then the word time is not used with the meaning of seconds or hours, but rather meaning something like instances or occasions (sorry, I couldn't come up with better synonyms).